# XPath to find duplicate attributes?

Tags: xml, xpath

What is the XPath to find (incorrectly formed, yes) elements with duplicate attributes?

Specifically they will look like this:

```
<relatedItem type="constituent" ID="c011" type="constituent">
```

Answer (score 3):

XPath is defined over XML.  What you show is not XML, because XML does not allow two attributes on the same element to have the same name.  Therefore, you cannot use XPath to select parts of your textual (non-XML) data.

Comment: Or to put it another way, before you can run XPath on it you have to successfully parse it, and you can't successfully parse it if it's not well-formed.